# How do I Integrate OpenERP 7.0 with external file hosting service?

Tags: web-services, file-upload, integration, odoo, xml-rpc

I am trying to integrate OpenERP 7.0 with an existing file hosting system in my institution. For that, I would present an upload form to users, and then send this file to the host via webservice, and would get back the id of the file on the remote server and store it on OpenERP database, with some other info such as file name, description and date / time of upload, for example...

It seams to me that I would have to build (fully or partly) a web client in order to do that, and I'm not exactly at ease with that idea, so I have a lot of questions on this subject. Please someone could give me some examples or point me in the right direction (I've been searching google for weeks on this matter and still didn't find any info on this subject).

My questions are:

```
1 - How do I present the upload form in xml? (I'm guessing that if I use the field.binary() in my model, the <input type="file" /> will be shown in the client, but then, the file will be stored in OpenERP database, and that's not what I want...)
2 - How do I contact the remote service and receive his response (both upload and download files)
3 - How do I build the view in XML to download files?
```

Many thanks to whoever helps in this matter!

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation for OpenERP XMLRPC

https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/

https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/web/rpc/

Better you can use middleware like bottle for web services other than OpenERP Web Service